# Django - query to sum value atribute from model in frontpage

Tags: django

I have a model class for Courses named "Curs" where i set a field with number of stundets (alocati_curs).
When i loop in frontpage to show all the courses existed i show them `{% for curs in profil.curs_set.all %}` ....
Also i can display the number of courses `{% with profil.curs_set.all.count as total_cursuri %}`....  .
But i dont't know how to make a query to get the total students (alocati_curs) from all the courses. Please help me :) . Thank you.

I tried `{% with profil.curs.alocati_curs_set.all.count as total_cursuri %}` and `{% for curs in profil.curs.alocati_curs_set.all %}` but is not working and im sure is not make a correct query.

Comment: Please don't compose queries in the template language: this should be implemented in the view.

Comment: Hi. I understand what you say that i have to make query in the view but i don't understand what you mean with template "language". Anyway, i don't know how to make that query to get the total of "alocati_curs" from all the courses even if i set it in views. Any help with this query ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to make a solution. I use Aggregation. In my view I import my model and from django Sum:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from cursuri.models import Curs
```

and in my function view I added:

```
alocati_curs_trainer = Curs.objects.filter(creator_curs=profil.id).aggregate(tac=Sum('alocati_curs'))
```

like this:

```
def trainerProfil(request, pk):
    profil = Profil.objects.get(id=pk)
    alocati_curs_trainer = Curs.objects.filter(creator_curs=profil.id).aggregate(tac=Sum('alocati_curs'))
    context = {'profil' : profil, 'alocati_curs_trainer' : alocati_curs_trainer}
    return render(request, 'utilizatori/profil.html', context)
```

and in front page I show with:

```
{{ alocati_curs_trainer.tac }}
```

and now I can see for each trainer how many students (aka alocati_cus) has in total for all the courses allocated to them.

If I want also to show all the stundent in all the courses I can by set this in the function (def trainerProfil) in view.

```
alocati_curs_total = Curs.objects.all().aggregate(tact=Sum('alocati_curs'))
```

and in  the page I show them with:

```
{{alocati_curs_total.tact }}
```

It work but im sure that maybe is another proffesional way to do this but that's all I managed to think now and work for me.